# Misplaced subplot after removing of y label

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart, subplot

I have two similar barcharts plotet with `grid.arrange` in two cols, side by side.
Since they share a common label for the y-axis I wanted to remove the label on the right subplot y-axis.
I do this with the following:

```
myplot2 <- arrangeGrob(q+
                         theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()), #....
```

This leads to a distorted / misplacement of the two subfigures. Before I removed the y-label, both subplots have exactly the same proportions and there x-axis are on the same level.

**Question**
How can I remove the y-axis-label of the right plot without changing the position of the two subplots.

**MRE**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(dplyr)
algorithm <- c(rep("0_DT",2),rep("1_RF",2),rep("2_MLP",2))
target <- rep(c("Some Data","Some Other Data"),3)
value <- runif(6,85,95) # Simulated Accuracies
data <- data.frame(target,algorithm,value)
p <- ggplot(data, aes(fill=algorithm, y=value, x=target)) + theme_classic()+
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(0.75), stat="identity", width = 0.65,colour="black",size=0.1) + 
  scale_fill_manual("Algorithm",
                    values = alpha(c("0_DT" = "#20639B", "1_RF" = "#3CAEA3", "2_MLP" = "#F6D55C"),0.8),
                    labels=c("DT","RF","MLP"))+
  scale_y_continuous("Accuracy in %",limits = c(0,100),oob = rescale_none,
                     # breaks= sort(c(seq(0,90,10),h)),
                     breaks= seq(0,100,10),
                     expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0.3,0.1))+
  theme(aspect.ratio =10/6)

# duplicate the plot for MRE
q <- p
myplot1 <- arrangeGrob(p,
                       top = textGrob("1", x = unit(0.05, "npc")
                                      , y   = unit(-0.5, "npc"), just=c("left","top"),
                                      gp=gpar(col="black", fontsize=18, fontfamily="Arial",fontface="bold")))
myplot2 <- arrangeGrob(q+
                         theme(axis.title.y =element_blank()),
                       top = textGrob("2", x = unit(0.05, "npc")
                                      , y   = unit(-0.5, "npc"), just=c("left","top"),
                                      gp=gpar(col="black", fontsize=18, fontfamily="Arial",fontface="bold")))

grid.arrange(myplot1,myplot2,ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please verify your code, when trying to run it, I get multiple erros on the generation of the dataframe (CI.Lower not present), graph part (oob = rescale_none) and the use of `arrange.grob`. Also, what about merging your dataframe and use facet_wrap to display both graph ?

Comment: Sorry just cutted the CI to keep it shorter and missed to verify it again. I eddited the mre to work properly. I am not quite sure what seems to be the problem with `ob = rescale_non` however commenting it out didn't seem to change the behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your datasets are sharing a similar structure like in your example, a possible solution is to bind them together as follow:

```r
data <-  data.frame(target,algorithm,value)
data2 <- data.frame(target,algorithm,value)
data$dataset <- "Dataset1"
data2$dataset <- "Dataset2"

DF <- rbind(data, data2)

            target algorithm    value  dataset
1        Some Data      0_DT 87.33034 Dataset1
2  Some Other Data      0_DT 89.65962 Dataset1
3        Some Data      1_RF 87.65973 Dataset1
4  Some Other Data      1_RF 93.57828 Dataset1
5        Some Data     2_MLP 85.45831 Dataset1
6  Some Other Data     2_MLP 89.42200 Dataset1
7        Some Data      0_DT 87.33034 Dataset2
8  Some Other Data      0_DT 89.65962 Dataset2
9        Some Data      1_RF 87.65973 Dataset2
10 Some Other Data      1_RF 93.57828 Dataset2
11       Some Data     2_MLP 85.45831 Dataset2
12 Some Other Data     2_MLP 89.42200 Dataset2
```

And then instead of using `grid.arrange`, you can simply use `facet_wrap` to display both graph with same y axis:

```r
labels = c(Dataset1 = "1",Dataset2 ="2")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x = target, y = value, fill = algorithm))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2())+
  facet_wrap(~dataset, scales = "free", labeller = labeller(dataset = labels))+ 
  scale_fill_manual("Algorithm",
                    values = alpha(c("0_DT" = "#20639B", "1_RF" = "#3CAEA3", "2_MLP" = "#F6D55C"),0.8),
                    labels=c("DT","RF","MLP"))+
  scale_y_continuous("Accuracy in %",limits = c(0,100),
                     breaks= seq(0,100,10),
                     expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0.3,0.1))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(aspect.ratio =10/6,
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 15, hjust = 0, face = "bold"))
```

[image]

---

**EDIT: Changing x order for one of the two facets**

As per your comments, you are looking to manipulate the order for only one of the two dataset. To do that, a possible solution is to create 4 x values, set the right order, display it and modify their labeling using the argument `labels` in `scale_x_discrete`.

First, generating new x values that are all differents. Here, I add a suffix to the x values of the second dataset by doing:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

DF %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Suffix = ifelse(dataset == "Dataset2",".22","")) %>%
  mutate(Target = paste(target, Suffix, sep = "")) %>%
  mutate(Target = factor(Target, 
                         levels = c("Some Data","Some Other Data","Some Other Data.22","Some Data.22")))

Source: local data frame [12 x 6]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 12 x 6
   target          algorithm value dataset  Suffix Target            
   <fct>           <fct>     <dbl> <chr>    <chr>  <fct>             
 1 Some Data       0_DT       87.3 Dataset1 ""     Some Data         
 2 Some Other Data 0_DT       89.7 Dataset1 ""     Some Other Data   
 3 Some Data       1_RF       87.7 Dataset1 ""     Some Data         
 4 Some Other Data 1_RF       93.6 Dataset1 ""     Some Other Data   
 5 Some Data       2_MLP      85.5 Dataset1 ""     Some Data         
 6 Some Other Data 2_MLP      89.4 Dataset1 ""     Some Other Data   
 7 Some Data       0_DT       87.3 Dataset2 ".22"  Some Data.22      
 8 Some Other Data 0_DT       89.7 Dataset2 ".22"  Some Other Data.22
 9 Some Data       1_RF       87.7 Dataset2 ".22"  Some Data.22      
10 Some Other Data 1_RF       93.6 Dataset2 ".22"  Some Other Data.22
11 Some Data       2_MLP      85.5 Dataset2 ".22"  Some Data.22      
12 Some Other Data 2_MLP      89.4 Dataset2 ".22"  Some Other Data.22
```

Now, you can pass this new variables as x value in `ggplot2` and remove the suffix in the labeling by using `labels` argument of `scale_x_discrete` such as:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

DF %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Suffix = ifelse(dataset == "Dataset2",".22","")) %>%
  mutate(Target = paste(target, Suffix, sep = "")) %>%
  mutate(Target = factor(Target, 
                         levels = c("Some Data","Some Other Data","Some Other Data.22","Some Data.22"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Target, y = value, fill = algorithm))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2())+
  facet_wrap(~dataset, scales = "free", labeller = labeller(dataset = labels))+ 
  scale_fill_manual("Algorithm",
                    values = alpha(c("0_DT" = "#20639B", "1_RF" = "#3CAEA3", "2_MLP" = "#F6D55C"),0.8),
                    labels=c("DT","RF","MLP"))+
  scale_y_continuous("Accuracy in %",limits = c(0,100),
                     breaks= seq(0,100,10),
                     expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0.3,0.1), labels = function(x) sub("\\..*$","",x))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(aspect.ratio =10/6,
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 15, hjust = 0, face = "bold"))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Didn't know about the `facet_wrap` (as I usually plot my data with python). Seems pretty elegant, upvoted for your effort. Will need some time to restructre my real plotting and see if this solves it

Comment: Sure ;) no rush. Maybe someone will find a `grid.arrange` solution that will fit your needs. `facet_wrap` is just an alternative in the particular case where you are sharing y axis and legend.

Comment: Pretty happy with the result for now. I minor problem I ran into is, that it is now hard to swap in the right plot the groups (so i.e. in the right subplot first `Some Data`and then `Some Other Data`) This probably would already qualify as a new question, and I dont want to be a help vampire. However if you would know a solution for that off the cuff, I would really apreciate it

Comment: What do you mean ? You want to have on the right plot "some other data" and then "data" ? in this order ?

Comment: Exactly but the left should stay as it is. Thank you already for your help. the facet_wrap made a for loop unnecessary and increased the code readability by quite a margin. I guess thats worth the accept as it solved my issue :)

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer ;) I edited my answer to show you how to reverse the order only for the second dataset. Let me know if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: On point perfect. I see that I have a lot to improve regarding my R plotting skills

Comment: Glad that it worked for you ;) Don't worry, you are on the good track based on your code ;)